# Bitten by some insect

Tags: insect-bites

About a week ago I was bitten by some insect during my sleep and it left two "bubbles" as shown in the image. Any idea what this is?

[Bitten hand Picture](https://ibb.co/i9rvvp)

Comment: Welcome to Health Stack Exchange. Personal medical questions are off-topic. You should consult your healthcare professional, as bites from different insects can be remarkably similar. Those could be bed bugs, fleas or other insects too. I hope they improve quickly! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar experience many times. But sometimes it might be just allergy not insect bite. Usually, if it is insect bite it is itchy which is body's response to the proteins left by the insect in case of the mosquito. Some times some other pests or spiders. It may take more than a week or just a few days. But if you're concerned or it is painful, please contact your GP or Aesthetic specialist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If it doesnt disapper in a while I might check the doctor out. Just in case!